# How can I show only vendor related products?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In my wordpress site Am using woocommerce & Dokan Multivendor plugin and  and now in related products all vendors products are showing for a specific store i dont need this.I need only for a particular store there related products should be shown is there any way to do it?

Example: i have 3 stores and there products A vendor,B vendor, C vendor in if i go in A vendor products list in related products all B and C vendor products also showing.So i need to show only A vendor related products.

Comment: If you add categories to your products, woocommerce will only show a product as related if they are in the same category. Otherwise you can use plugins such as this https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-related-products-for-woocommerce/